# How to investigate high CPU for dmeventd (lvm2 / xfs)

Tags: lvm, centos7, xfs

I have three CentOS 7.2.1511 Servers that started showing dmeventd at the top of the cpu utilization (single core).

They are running docker and apache mesos.

Even when I shutdown docker and mesos the load doesn't drop for dmeventd

What would be the correct way to find the root cause of the load?

No high I/O just one core at 100%

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this too. Might be https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1220529 ?

**Update June 2017:**
Red Hat released https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2016-0964.html. If the problem is related to the issue mentioned above, a simple `yum update` should fix it. The latest lvm2 package in RHEL/CentOS 7 should include the fixes as well.